# Matter JS - option list - Am I blind?

Tags: javascript, canvas, matter.js

New to MatterJS.

In the example, theres is options to draw circle, rectangle, etc.
Those options are like using Sprite, FillStyle...

I see no where in the documentation the list of options and values related to that.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: If everything else brakes, a look on the source code will help you

Comment: thanks, I checked in the source code. It is true that the options can be found there, but it is not the easiest way to understand the framework. Do you have any idea of a cheatsheet somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, Not at all. But after working with several poorly documented frameworks I think a look at the source code is much more convenient than using google for hours...:-)

Answer (score 3):

From reading the [source code](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/7894b4b44d41077200cfe209c01b35b595db90f4/build/matter.js#L71) of matter.js I found the defaults for options. Doesn't explain what each does but at least here's a list of them:

```js
var defaults = {
  id: Common.nextId(),
  type: 'body',
  label: 'Body',
  parts: [],
  plugin: {},
  angle: 0,
  vertices: Vertices.fromPath('L 0 0 L 40 0 L 40 40 L 0 40'),
  position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  force: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  torque: 0,
  positionImpulse: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  constraintImpulse: { x: 0, y: 0, angle: 0 },
  totalContacts: 0,
  speed: 0,
  angularSpeed: 0,
  velocity: { x: 0, y: 0 },
  angularVelocity: 0,
  isSensor: false,
  isStatic: false,
  isSleeping: false,
  motion: 0,
  sleepThreshold: 60,
  density: 0.001,
  restitution: 0,
  friction: 0.1,
  frictionStatic: 0.5,
  frictionAir: 0.01,
  collisionFilter: {
    category: 0x0001,
    mask: 0xFFFFFFFF,
    group: 0
  },
  slop: 0.05,
  timeScale: 1,
  render: {
    visible: true,
    opacity: 1,
    sprite: {
      xScale: 1,
      yScale: 1,
      xOffset: 0,
      yOffset: 0
    },
    lineWidth: 0
  }
};
```

As taras pointed out the object's [properties](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html) are initialized from these options.

Answer (score 0):

These options are body's properties, described in `Matter.Body` module: http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#properties

Answer (score 0):

I think that in those examples, **matter.js** is handling the drawing of the shapes of the bodies itself through `Render.bodies` (inside matter.js file) and related functions.

In case anyone want to draw lines, circles or rectangles, they can access the canvas that matter.js uses, and draw them via lineTo, arc functions of canvas, I guess.